# Kernel of set of independent vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, measure-theory

I am asked to find an example of a sequence of linearly independent vectors $\{y_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ s.t. $\ker((y_1,y_2,y_3,\ldots))\neq\emptyset$ 
(alternatively, some vector $(a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots)\neq 0$ s.t. $\sum a_ny_n=0$)

Any hint is appreciated

Comment: What is the kernel of a collection of vectors? Kernels are never empty in any case you you likely mean $\neq 0$.

Comment: Please do not vandalise your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n\in\Bbb N$ let $y_0=\langle y_{0,k}:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$, where

- $y_{n,n}=1$ for each $n\ge 0$,
- $y_{n,n-1}=1$ for each $n\ge 1$, and
- $y_{n,k}=0$ otherwise.

Thus,

$$\begin{align*}
y_0&=\langle 1,0,0,0,0,0,0,\ldots\rangle\\
y_1&=\langle 1,1,0,0,0,0,0,\ldots\rangle\\
y_2&=\langle 0,1,1,0,0,0,0,\ldots\rangle\\
y_3&=\langle 0,0,1,1,0,0,0,\ldots\rangle\\
y_4&=\langle 0,0,0,1,1,0,0,\ldots\rangle\\
&\;\;\vdots
\end{align*}$$

I’ll leave it to you to verify that these are linearly independent and to find a suitable $\langle a_0,a_1,a_2,\ldots\rangle$; if you get completely stuck, there’s a further hint in the spoiler-protected block below.

> Try an alternating series.

Comment: Nevermind my question lol